# ActiveWeb: mocking injected service

Tags: activeweb

When mocking a service injected into a controller, a service method should return a mocked object, something like that:

```
public class EmptyInterventionServiceMock implements InterventionService {
    @Override
    public Intervention findByInvoiceNumber(String invoiceNumber, String language) {
        return mockedIntervention(invoiceNumber, language);
    }

    protected Intervention mockedIntervention(String invoiceNumber, String language) {
        return mock(Intervention.class);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to mock some values to be return by the above mocked object (`Intervention`) to test fi they should be present in the generated JSON template ?

For example, depending on if `Intervention` has `spare parts`, `services`, `states` (all of them are just collections of other objects), etc. If so, JSON should contain the corresponding keys: `services: [{....}]`, `states: [{}]`, etc.

It would be nice to get the mocked object in the test and stub its return values. The only way I see to achieve that for the moment is to create a separate `Mock` service class and inject it in a test class as follows:

```
public class InterventionsControllerSpec extends ControllerSpec {

    @Before
    public void before() {
        Injector injector = injector().bind(InterventionService.class).to(BaseInterventionServiceMock.class).create();
    }
```

Where `BaseInterventionServiceMock` just extends `EmptyInterventionServiceMock` and stubs some methods return values by overriding its `mockedIntervention` method:

```
public class BaseInterventionServiceMock extends EmptyInterventionServiceMock {

    @Override
    protected Intervention mockedIntervention(String invoiceNumber, String language) {
        Intervention intervention = mock(Intervention.class);
        when(intervention.getString("ITV_DOCUMENT_NUMBER")).thenReturn("123");
        when(intervention.getString("ITV_INVOICE")).thenReturn(invoiceNumber);
...
etc.
```

As it is far from ideal, I wonder if there is a DRYer way to do that ?

Thank you.

Comment: Anyway, mocking the values DOES NOT work this way: `when(intervention.getString("itv_document_number")).thenReturn("123");` when displaying it in the template like this: `"document_number" : "${intervention.itv_document_number!}"`. It seems like without overriding the corresponding `getter` method in the model and mocking that method, it will not work. Any ideas ? Or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not missing anything. Your assumptions are correct. Creating a mock subclass of a service is how we do the testing. If you want a more elegant way, you can submit a proposal for consideration: https://github.com/javalite/activeweb/issues for consideration.

Comment: OK, thank you. Depending on the JSON data to generate and its structure, etc., the number of mocks can grow considerably. The only thing it is possible to test is just the presence of keys in the JSON map. And for every case I'll have to create a separate service mock to override the `mockedIntervention` method. I'll see if it is still worth to do that.